# Section content using MediaWiki API

Tags: wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I'm using the MediaWiki API to get the content of a Wikipedia page like this in JSON.

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&titles=New_York&prop=extracts
```

I'd like each section to be separated out instead of having the entire content of the page as one value.  I know you can get each section like this but I want it to also include the content with each section.

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=parse&prop=sections&page=New_York
```

Is this possible to do with the API?

Answer (score 3):

If you know the number of the section which you want you can get the contents through `action=parse` with the `section` parameter. E.g. the "19th century" section of the New_York article would be:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=New_York&format=json&prop=wikitext&section=4
```

To get the section number you can use

```
 http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=parse&prop=sections&page=New_York
```

and then find the `index` corresponding to your section title (`line`). In this case `"line":"19th century","index":"4"`.